Lots of course sludge from copper electroplating
I'm trying to electroplate copper onto copper.
Copper was cleaned in white vinegar to remove oxides.
I'm using copper sulfate for my electrolyte.
Hitting it with 10-12 volts dc and about 2 amps.
The anode is slowly consumed by the process.
The cathode loads up with what looks like a miniaturized coral reef. It kinda looks how iron filings look when you place a magnet on one side of the paper and filings on the other side then move the magnet around a little --- best as I can describe it.
When you pull the cathode out of the electrolyte all these "loose" particles kinda' brush off, and the electrolyte container has it all over the bottom.
WHAT AM I DOING WRONG? WHAT'S CAUSING THIS ISSUE? HOW DO I AVOID/ELIMINATE IT?
Studied into this process --- seemed really simple and straightforward --- proving not to be, at least for me.
Any advise, help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Too high voltage (majority of power would be Ohmic loses) , too high current density  and lack of research about ideal solution for electroplating to ensure the best surface quality.

Voltage should not be higher than 2 Volts.

This question is similar to: Copper layer doesn't stick after Copper electroplating. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Potential (i.e., volts) is like acceleration of the charge carriers and an eventual speed of travel (reduced by friction of other less quickly moving or immobile molecules in the solution), current (or amps) how many of charge carriers per unit of time travel across a line. Its like people rushing into a place, if the process is too fast, they don't have time to properly settle into "their seats" and hence the somewhat loose contact, mechanically speaking. In addition "lost of [...] sludge" isn't really a quantification to put things in perspective vs. overall scale of operation.

In addition, do you have an idea about the purity of the copper to be refined (not only on the surface which you mention was cleaned, but the bulk)?  Cu to be refined by electrolysis already is of high purity (around 98%, ref) before electrolysis is engaged.

See also wikipedia.org - Copper_electroplating#Types_of_plating_chemistries

See Ch. IV, § 137: https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/22784
